# Submit button echoing a wrong array value

Tags: php, arrays

i design an array value from my database using to be view in a table using this code

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($levels); $i++){
$level = $levels[$i];
?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo ($level->getLevel()); ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo ($level->getAmount()); ?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo ($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?>
</td>
<td>
<button type="submit" value="Recycle" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Recycle</button>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"      aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<?php                                           
echo ($level->getPotentialEarning(''));
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

which worked very fine, but the only problem am facing is whenever the submit button is clicked, it echo the last value of the array instead of echoing the value in it fronts

Comment: After `for` is over `$level` holds __last__ value.

Comment: @u_mulder, so please what is the way out

Comment: Can you expand your HTML to include everything from the opening `<form>` tag to the closing `</form>`  ?

Comment: @Chris no html form tag is include

Comment: When you clicked the submit button, do you refresh the same page, or is an ajax handler or what?, please be more specific

Comment: @OsDev no, i just view it using bootstrap modal to echo it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not echoing the correct Potential Earning is because the variable `$level` that is used is that of the last item in the array and not that taken from the button click.

You can use javascript to show the correct value by adding a button onclick event

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onclickbutton(<?php echo ($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?> )">
    Recycle
</button>
```

then just after the table replace the div elements with just this

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <p id="clicked">
        &nbsp;
    </p>
</div>
```

then either in your header or script file add

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function onclickbutton(value) {
        document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>
```